# How do I create a POST request using AutoHotKey V2?

Tags: automation, autohotkey

How do I create a POST Rest API request using AutoHotKey V2? Every existing script I can find on the internet applies only to AutoHotKey V1. Are there existing utility scripts that faciliate this process?

Comment: It's still the same language, mainly just syntactically different. If you know AHK, the difference between v1 and v2 shouldn't cause any issues. If you have not learned the differences with v2 yet, I recommend you check [this](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/v2-changes.htm) wonderful documentation page. But long story short: the same `ComObj` approach, which is you have found with a Google search, works exactly the same for v2. If you're looking for copy-pastable code and can only find v1 code, maybe use v1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic example of a function that uses a COM Object for HTTP Requests.

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0.11+

url := 'https://reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/new/'
MsgBox(http('Post', url))

http(verb, url) {
    ; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttprequest
    web := ComObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1')
    web.Open(verb, url)
    web.Send()
    web.WaitForResponse()
    return web.ResponseText
}
```